# Disable Save as in all browsers

Tags: browser

I have a content sharing site, Can I disable save as option from all browsers ,so that my content doesn't get copied down. I am using javascript to disable right click , but even then my content is being copied down by some bloggers. I need a full proof software or tool that can stop others from copying my content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Disable HTML view source or Encrypt Html elements programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427747/how-to-disable-html-view-source-or-encrypt-html-elements-programatically)

Comment: Anything you send to a browser can be copied. Anything you put in place to try and stop it can be circumvented with minimal effort. There are copyright laws in place to protect your intellectual property, but using them might not be practicable. Be flattered people think your material worthy of copying.

Comment: am not worried about my html code , am worried about the content that is being displayed on site

Comment: What kind of content is it that you want to protect? If it's for example images, they don't even need to be downloaded, they can just be copied doing a screen dump, so then you can't possibly protect them with anything in the browser.

Comment: my url is [avatto.com](https://avatto.com), Its an educational site, so whatever study material is prepared by my team, that's being copied down and hosted on other blogs, and when i requested a fellow blogger to remove my content , I was shocked...He told me that I don't own internet and he is free to copy from anywhere. Now totally  clueless what to do..?